# Multiple 'includes' within a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm looking for a way to access both the 'fit' and 'gif' keys inside my object. Right now, I can only display one or the other on the page - 'fit' being an image and 'gif' being a gif.

I think possibly I could use .match but i'm not really sure the correct syntax

Thanks

```
const sizeMappings = {
master: '1280',
  small: '192w',
  small_fit: '192w',
  medium: '384w',
  medium_low_res: '288w',
  medium_fit: '384w',
  medium_gif: '384w',
  medium_fit_low_res: '288w',
  large: '768w',
  large_fit: '768w',
  large_gif: '768w',
  xlarge: '1280w',
  xlarge_fit: '1280w',
}

const getSrcSet = (renditions, fit, gif) => {
  const sizes = Object.keys(sizeMappings)
    .map((key) => {
      if (fit && !key.includes('fit')) return null
      const mapping = `${renditions[key]} ${sizeMappings[key]}`
      return mapping
    })

  return sizes
    .filter(el => el !== null)
    .join(',')
}
```

Comment: So you want to return both the "regular" and the "gif" version of a given size in an array?

Comment: @Chris yes thats correct. Right now, I can only seem to return the 'fit' or regular image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `filter()` instead of `map()` since you are actually looking to extract a subset of your array. Then, just match each key to be the given size name + `"_gif"` or size name + `"_fit"`.

```js
const sizeMappings = {
  master: '1280',
  small: '192w',
  small_fit: '192w',
  medium: '384w',
  medium_low_res: '288w',
  medium_fit: '384w',
  medium_gif: '384w',
  medium_fit_low_res: '288w',
  large: '768w',
  large_fit: '768w',
  large_gif: '768w',
  xlarge: '1280w',
  xlarge_fit: '1280w',
}

let size = "large";  //change me

let arr = Object.keys(sizeMappings).filter(
  (key) => (key === size + "_fit" || key === size + "_gif")
);

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter first and then map the results as you wish:

```
const getSrcSet = (renditions, fit, gif) => {
  return Object.keys(sizeMappings)
    .filter(key => fit && key.includes('fit') || gif && key.includes('gif'))
    .map(key => `${renditions[key]} ${sizeMappings[key]}`)
    .join(',')
  }
```